# Unable to serialize the session state

Tags: c#, asp.net

Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and
'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects,
and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are
not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization
is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Unable to serialize the
>   session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will
>   serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable
>   objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same
>   restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom
>   session state store in 'Custom' mode.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SerializationException: Type 'Examination' in Assembly
>   'App_Code.aw9uvznn, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.]
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType
>   type) +7735723
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type
>   type, StreamingContext context) +258
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
>   +111    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter) +161
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter) +51
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object
>   graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
>   +410    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
>   +134    System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1577
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to serialize the session state. In
>   'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session
>   state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or
>   MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies
>   if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in
>   'Custom' mode.]
>   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value,
>   BinaryWriter writer) +1662
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.WriteValueToStreamWithAssert(Object
>   value, BinaryWriter writer) +34
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Serialize(BinaryWriter
>   writer) +606
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.Serialize(SessionStateStoreData
>   item, Stream stream) +239
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.SerializeStoreData(SessionStateStoreData
>   item, Int32 initialStreamSize, Byte[]& buf, Int32& length) +72
>   System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext
>   context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean
>   newItem) +87
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object
>   source, EventArgs eventArgs) +560
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnEndRequest(Object source,
>   EventArgs eventArgs) +160
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +68    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
>
> ---

http://myweb.somee.com/login.aspx
Username: demo
Password: user

Click on take exam
select ASP.NET and click start exam.

You will see the error below. I need help to remove this error.
sidra.raheel@yahoo.com

Download source code from link below:
http://www.4shared.com/zip/-KF0Zjsi/Quiz_Engine_in_ASP.html

Answer (score 6):

So, mark `Examination` as `[Serializable]`. Done.

Comment: Or implement ISerializable on Examination.

Comment: @AKDeveloper And, obviously, do the same for every custom class which you will be storing to session.

Comment: You should add some code when asking a question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask